# VS2012 Express for Web: Source file 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I am getting this error when i am creating a .NET 4.5 Class library. When i do  same with target environment 4.0 its working fine.

I get the error when i try to build the solution.

I tried this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/73e67f3a-c575-4c73-a71d-ed7a2aeabb50/csc-error-cs2001-source-file-cwindowstempnetframeworkversionv40assemblyattributescs?forum=msbuild

But its not working as well.

I have .net framework 4.5 installed.

Comment: Google "windows cleanup temp folder" to get a start on fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

try to rebot the system or just VS or logout/login (to Windows user account).and when you open VS .clean the solution and rebuild it and makes sure there’s a generated file in the TEMP directory called NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs

Comment: Its not woorking. My windows/TEMP has no such file.

Answer (score 0):

this problam appear because the building account lost it s permission to the temp folder: C:\Windows\Temp\ .try to change all permission to your account, including read/write/full control.
 Go to the folder C:\Windows\Temp. or the folder C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ -Right-click on thoes folder and select Properties.

2. It'll open its Properties window. Now go to "Security" tab and select your username from the given list. You'll see that it doesn't have full control.
   and take control of your temp folder

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before; It was caused when I tried to change the target framework of a project after it was created using a different framework version.  Try creating a NEW project using the framework you need and manually copy over the source files.

Comment: Where exactly i need to copy the source files? By source file you mean the entire solution?

Comment: Create the new project and then goto Project-Add Existing File (or something like that) and browse to the old solution and select all code files.  Only bring the code files, don't copy over files that you do not clearly remember writing.